# ios 8.1 simulator -- Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP

Tags: ios, xcode, cross-domain, ios-simulator

I am testing web pages locally for display on iOS devices using XCode's iOS Simulator. I just upgraded XCode to 6.1 and when testing with iOS 8.1 in the simulator I now get the error:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:.... Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP**

This does not happen when testing with iOS 7.1 nor did it happen with XCode 6 and iOS 8.

Other than uploading the content to a server is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this that could be shared?

Comment: Not yet, but I'm on the verge of installing a web server, probably XAMPP, which I already have on my Windows machine. That should work.

Comment: Check working answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996292/ios-wkwebview-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http