# iOS - WKWebView Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

Hi i'm trying to load an html that is in the main Bundle with WKWebView this worked perfectly with UIWebView but now i have an error, the files in the html does not load send an error in the console : "XMLHttpRequest cannot load"

[image: Consola form simulator]

[image: Simulator]

this is an example http://proyectoshm.com/esferas/dosaguas/dosaguascitta.html of the content embedded.

My code:

```
let folder = "maquetas/esferas/\(esfera)"

let resourcePath = Bundle.main.resourcePath
let subdir = URL(fileURLWithPath:resourcePath!).appendingPathComponent(folder, isDirectory: true)

guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html", inDirectory: folder) else {
    print("no se encontró path")
    return

}
print(subdir.path)


let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: path)
 print(url.path)
 vistaweb = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)

vistaweb.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: subdir)

self.view.addSubview(vistaweb)
```

Comment: Try this `vistaweb.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")`

Comment: Like a charm, thanks a lot ! i  never found this

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To resolve it, you need to turn `allowFileAccessFromFileURLs` on from `WKPreferences`

## Swift

```
webView.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs")
```

## Objective-C

```
[webView.configuration.preferences setValue:@YES forKey:@"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"];
```

Comment: You may also need to use "allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs"  in addition to the above. See my answer

Comment: Add comment to your answer that it is undocumented feature and might stop working unexpectedly.

Comment: It seems it does not work anymore (tested on iOS 15.6)

Comment: @gomezo 
I tested it on iOS 17.2 and it seems to work for me.

Is it different for each OS?

Answer (score 4):

**File Access and universal File access (In case of reading media from device)**

```
[webView.configuration.preferences setValue:@YES forKey:@"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"];
[webView.configuration setValue:@YES forKey:@"allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs"];
```

Answer (score 2):

For Xamarin.iOS devs:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration config = webView.Configuration;
config.Preferences.SetValueForKey( FromObject( true ), new NSString( "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs" ) );
config.SetValueForKey( FromObject( true ), new NSString( "allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" ) );
```